# Можно ли настроить CUPS так, чтобы новая задача не уходила на печать, а вставала в очередь со статусом Приостановлена?

Tags: c++, linux, c, debian, cups

Можно ли настроить `CUPS` так, чтобы новая задача не уходила сразу на печать, а вставала в очередь со статусом `Приостановлена`?
В `cupsd.conf` нужных параметров не нашел. Код [из доки](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/project/opssrc/cups/cups-1.4.4/doc/help/api-cups.html) после выполнения `cupsFinishDocument(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, dest->name);` тоже сразу кидает на принтер, хотя функция `cupsCreateJob` создаёт задачу как раз в статусе `Приостановлено`. Только вот как к задаче прикрепить документ без последующей его печати.

Comment: теоретически настроить можно. опция такая есть: [hold-new-jobs](https://github.com/apple/cups/blob/master/doc/help/man-cupsd.conf.html#L394)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, только это не опция а команда ipp; теоретически её нужно [отправить](https://www.cups.org/doc/cupspm.html#sending-ipp-requests)... хотя здравый смысл подсказывает, что такое поведение должно как-то настраиваться по умолчанию...

Comment: Вот тут на форуме https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1200040 человек спрашивает как отключить то, что вы хотите включит. Может поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, как подсказали выше, сделал запрос на смену конфига принтера:

```
ipp_t* request = ::ippNewRequest(IPP_HOLD_NEW_JOBS);
::ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_URI, "printer-uri", nullptr, "ipp://localhost:631/printers/printer123");
ipp_t* response = ::cupsDoRequest(http, request, "/admin/");
```

после чего в конфиг-файле для принтеров `/etc/cups/printers.conf` у выбранного принтера появилась строчка `Reason hold-new-jobs`, которой, думаю, будет достаточно для выполнения описанного функционала.

Задачи ставятся в состоянии Ожидание.